# can i debug or trace formally by help of zend studio

Tags: php, zend-studio

can i debug or trace formally by help of zend studio 
i am not having any debugger is any debugger is bydefault integrated in zend debugger or not help me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Zend Studio comes preinstalled with Zend Debugger.

Also see

- [Zend Forum > Sticky Notes: Setting Up Zend Debugger](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962)
- [Zend Webinar: Troubleshooting PHP with Zend Studio](http://files.zend.com/webinar/Studio-PHP-Troubleshooting/Studio_PHP_Troubleshooting.html)